# Regex function to for a sentence with commas and text which may even extend over a line

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty new to Python and I just started learning regex. I'm trying to define a function that takes as input a string returns the number of occurrences where there's an instance where there's something like ', This is my regex practice, '. Here the texts are between commas but there's a space after both commas. There are chances of this happening over 2 lines. But I wanna calculate only if its in a single line.

sample file https://regex101.com/r/922t4S/1

In this sample file,  there's an instance such as ', nearly napping, '. How can I write regex for such statement where there are chances that the sentence may extend over to a new line. How can I count them?

Here's my code:

```
def count(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    x = f.readlines()
#   pattern=re.compile(",\s+\w,")
#   pattern=re.compile(',\s+[a-zA-Z]*\s*,')
    l=0
    for i in x:
        k=re.findall(pattern, i)
        l=l+len(k)
    return l
```

I tried 2 ways as commented but both make no sense when I try to visualize on a regex tester. Please help.

Comment: Can you describe how does your two attempts not work?

Comment: Note that the sample text only has one line.

Comment: I shouldn't have changed the poem to inclined.. I edited it the way the poem is on the net.

Comment: Regarding my regex, both of them didn't give me any matches.

Comment: I still don't see any phrases surrounded by commas that are split across multiple lines. You gave an example of what to match in the poem, but can you also give an example of what _not_ to match? i.e. what text is between 2 commas, and is not in a single line?

Comment: Yeah sorry abt that..ill edit it exacly as per the text..but u can find the exact text here: https://regex101.com/r/922t4S/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209420/discussion-between-sweeper-and-jblack).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
,\h*.+?\h*,
```

The important features of this regex:

- `\h` matches horizontal space, so it excludes newlines characters
- the quantifier `*` is used on `\h` because there could be any number (including 0) of whitespaces between the text and the comma
- `.` matches all non-newline characters, as opposed to the `\w` you used, which only matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which does not include whitespace.
- `+?` means "match [lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)".

EDIT:

I just realised you are reading the file line by line and applying the regex line by line, so matches will *never* be across lines even if you used `\s`. Still, my last three bullets apply,